# DEBUG: Crawled (403) in Python 3 Web Scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

I was trying to scrape a site for practice, but I kept getting HTTP 403 error. How to get request permissions?

Here is my code:

```
from typing import List

import scrapy


class ResearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pesquisa'
    start_urls: list[str] = ['https://www.imovelweb.com.br/imoveis-aluguel-paraiba.html?iv_=__iv_p_1_a_17808488596_g_139189246037_w_dsa-1687663569069_h_20089_ii_20098_d_c_v__n_g_c_611609016411_k__m__l__t__e__r__vi__']

    def parse(self, response):
        for pesquisa in response.css('.js-listing-labels-link'):
            yield{
                'address': pesquisa.css('.property-card__address::text').get(),
                'area': pesquisa.css('.js-property-card-detail-area::text').get(),
                'rooms': pesquisa.css('.js-property-detail-rooms .js-property-card-value::text').get(),
                'bathroom': pesquisa.css('.js-property-detail-bathroom .js-property-card-value::text').get(),
                'garages': pesquisa.css('.js-property-detail-garages .js-property-card-value::text').get(),
                'prices': pesquisa.css('p::text').get()[5:-1]}
```

command to be executed by terminal:

```
scrapy shell
fetch('https://www.imovelweb.com.br/imoveis-paraiba.html')
```

The error I get is:

```
2022-09-16 14:11:14 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 1292395054608 on C:\Users\Familia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/pub
licsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-09-16 14:11:14 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 1292395054608 released on C:\Users\Familia\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org
-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-09-16 14:11:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.imovelweb.com.br/imoveis-paraiba.html> (referer: None)
```

Answer (score 1):

The website is under cloudflare protection.

```
https://www.imovelweb.com.br/imoveis-aluguel-paraiba.html?iv_=__iv_p_1_a_17808488596_g_139189246037_w_dsa-1687663569069_h_20089_ii_20098_d_c_v__n_g_c_611609016411_k__m__l__t__e__r__vi__ is using Cloudflare CDN/Proxy!

https://www.imovelweb.com.br/imoveis-aluguel-paraiba.html?iv_=__iv_p_1_a_17808488596_g_139189246037_w_dsa-1687663569069_h_20089_ii_20098_d_c_v__n_g_c_611609016411_k__m__l__t__e__r__vi__ is using Cloudflare SSL!
```

Comment: and the website: https://www.imovelweb.com.br/imoveis-paraiba.html?

Comment: Your commented url is also in cloudflare.

Comment: So what you recommendicion for me? I looking stackoverflow about cloudscraper or User agent, but I don't understaning

Comment: To add user agent will not work here . The better solution is to use selenium

Comment: Firstly use cloudscraper if not work use selenium if selenium didn't work use proxy if proxy didn't work sorry for that nothing to recommand